# do-release-upgrade via ssh

Tags: ssh, vps, do-release-upgrade

I am using Ubuntu on a vps via ssh. I run do-release-upgrade try to update from 12.04 to 12.10. The update seems to be successful. But after restarting, I can not login via ssh( bad file number 22) . It seems that the ssh daemon is not running. I can recovery from previous backups, but how can I update successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using port 1022.
You should have gotten a warning when updating that a second sshd daemon is started on that port.